# Drop rows in the dataframe if a cell does not contains a substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
id     A       B       C
123  Tom-ok    2      Red
454  Alan     4-ok    Blue
546  Bryan      5      Yellow
210   May      1      Purple-ok
```

I want to drop rows *without* the substring `-ok`
I tried this but didn't work:

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df.drop([col for col in df.columns if ~df[col].str.contains('-ok').any()], axis=0)
```

my expected output is without Bryan's row.

```
id     A       B       C
123  Tom-ok    2      Red
454  Alan     4-ok    Blue
210   May      1      Purple-ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps can be done in a cleaner manner but this should work:

```
df['condition'] = df.applymap(lambda x: '-ok' in str(x)).apply(lambda x:any(x),axis=1)
df = df.loc[~df.condition].drop(columns='condition')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df = df[pd.DataFrame([df[col].str.contains('-ok') for col in df.columns]).T.any(axis=1)]
```

Giving:

```
          A     B          C
id                          
123  Tom-ok     2        Red
454    Alan  4-ok       Blue
210     May     1  Purple-ok
```

The thing you index by is a boolean mask of rows that contain `'-ok'`:

```
# pd.DataFrame([df[col].str.contains('-ok') for col in df.columns]).T.any(axis=1)

id
123     True
454     True
546    False
210     True
dtype: bool
```

I can't find how to do an equivalent to `str.contains` on the whole DataFrame (or on the rows), so I am looping over the columns and transposing (so I suppose there may be a better approach).